# How to make generic function to delete data in two Realm tables?

Tags: ios, swift, realm

Code:

```
  class Realm_manager {

        private init() {}

        static let shared = Realm_manager()

        let realm = try! Realm()

         func deleteObjects<T: Object,T2: Object>(id: String,obj1: T,obj2: T2) {
             try! realm.write {
            realm.delete(realm.objects(T2.self).filter("set_id=%@", id))
            realm.delete(realm.objects(T.self).filter("id=%@", id))
        }
    }
    }
```

function call in VC:

```
Realm_manager.shared.deleteObjects(id: array[indexPath.row].id, obj1: className1, obj2: className2)
```

Error in VC:

> Cannot convert value of type 'className1.Type' to expected argument type 'Object'

How can I solve this error?

Comment: Are you sure you mean delete **all** data in these two tables? if so then there are far easier and faster ways to delete **all** data.

Comment: Hej Jay, my mistake. I wanted to delete one row in one table, and all rows in another table whose foreign key is the same as first table's deleted row's primary key. However I have solved this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How you're getting/setting className1 and className2?
Should work like:

```
let object = Object()
deleteObjects(id: "1234", obj1: object, obj2: object)
```

Actually, your `deleteObjects` don't need to know anything about real objects.
Could:

```
func deleteObjects<T: Object,T2: Object>(id: String, obj1: T.Type, obj2: T2.Type) {
    try! realm.write {
        realm.delete(realm.objects(T2.self).filter("set_id=%@", id))
        realm.delete(realm.objects(T.self).filter("id=%@", id))
    }
}
```

And call:

```
deleteObjects(id: "1234", obj1: Object.self, obj2: Object.self)
```

Or more convinient would be:

```
func deleteObjectsWith(id: String, withTypes types: [Object.Type]) {
    try! realm.write {
        types.forEach { objectType in
            let objects = realm.objects(objectType).filter("set_id=%@", id)
            realm.delete(objects)
        }
    }
}
```

And call:

```
deleteObjectsWith(id: "1234", withTypes: [Object.self, Object.self])
```